# Set white glow on cardview

Tags: android, layout, cardview

[image: This is what I got]I presume, this is quite a basic question but I had to ask it because of my attempt for finding relevant answers for setting white glow on MaterialCardView or simply CardView goes in vain, They were offering setting border color instead, now anyone please bother yourself to enlighten me with the proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have a green glow around white cardview

[image]

Try this code

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
       >
 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: two card views? isn't it unreliable?

Comment: Why is it unreliable? I wanted perfect curve, thats why i added 2 similar cardviews

Comment: I need glow, it is more likely a border instead.

Comment: Wish I could show you how it looks, but I assume, you have now some idea about it.

Comment: Yes, but either you try shadow or a glow like border. Do you need a blink?

Comment: Now look, I updated the question with a screenshot, I already achieved, but it doesn't glow anyway, I wonder, If this is possible anyway.

Comment: Don't mind the color, I'll change it to white later.

Comment: Just put your CardView in FrameLayout, add some padding to FrameLayout and set background drawable. You can create a 9 path drawable to have full control on its look.

Comment: I think, I'll do it.

Comment: @RadekJ can you share code for your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use 9-patch image like this one:

[image: http://static.rjuszczyk.com/images/green_outline.9.png]

and apply it to a FrameLayout, then put your content with white background inside

[image: 9-patch image preview in android studio]

Or for API 28+ you can try using `android:outlineSpotShadowColor="#5500FF00"` attribute

Comment: This doesnt work!?