# How can I give blur effect in android studio?

Tags: android, html, kotlin, paint, glow

How can I do to give the lighting effect to the edges of the letter in android studio? The card I use is an image and I want to give it the border and lighting

I tried to put in an image but it is too complicated for me

[image: 1]

Comment: You can check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55273940/set-white-glow-on-cardview

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: @Learn2Code What's the problem? It's just an image... it does work... (I have no idea why I received a notification for you comment).